# siunitx in a table: how to align on the plus-minus?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, siunitx

I'm using `siunitx` for a column of numbers with uncertainty in my table. Is it possible to align the column so that both the part before and the part after the plus-minus sign are aligned?

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[separate-uncertainty=true]{siunitx}
\begin{document}

Table 1: Desired alignment.\\

\begin{tabular}{lr@{\hspace{2pt}}r@{\hspace{2pt}}rl}
First row & $-2.3$&\textpm&$10.4$&*\\
Second row & $-13.3$&\textpm&$5.6$&**\\
\end{tabular}

\vspace{1cm}

Table 2: What I can get with siunitx.\\

\begin{tabular}{lrl}
First row & \num{-2.3(104)}&*\\
Second row & \num{-13.3(56)}&**\\
\end{tabular}\\

\end{document}
```

If that isn't possible, is there a way to get the plus-minus signs aligned?

Comment: Have a look at the `S` column type of siunitx.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I did check that chapter in the manual but it didn't seem to solve my problem, should I read it again?

Comment: Remember with an `S` column you should not use `\num`

Comment: Aha, thank you both! I thought the few paragraphs on tabular data was everything about `S`, but there's several pages more in the chapter on package options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could let siunitx do the alignment for you if you use an `S` column:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[separate-uncertainty=true]{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=-2.1+-2.1]l}
First row & -2.3(104) &*\\
Second row & -13.3(56) &**\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Are you sure that the large gap before the `*` is what you want? It looks very odd. They would look so much better if they were part of the numbers.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[separate-uncertainty=true]{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=-2.1+-2.1{**}]}
First row & -2.3(104)*\\
Second row & -13.3(56)**\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had missed a part of the `S` documentation, thank you very much! In my actual document I had shrunk the cell spacing before the asterisks, but having `S` solve this too looks great!